# Determining whether one array contains the contents of another array in JavaScript/CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

In JavaScript, how do I test that one array has the elements of another array?

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[8, 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9].function_name(arr1) # => true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if array contains all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606337/check-if-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

No set function does this, but you can simply do an ad-hoc array intersection and check the length.

```
[8, 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9].filter(function (elem) {
    return arr1.indexOf(elem) > -1;
}).length == arr1.length
```

A more efficient way to do this would be to use `.every` which will short circuit in falsy cases.

```
arr1.every(elem => arr2.indexOf(elem) > -1);
```

Comment: This certainly takes the least amount of code but it does a complete enumeration rather than stopping when it realizes that an element is not in arr1. So it would probably be less performant than @valentinas' solution.

Comment: is there an any alternate?

Comment: @bygrace how about if array.some { elem => arr2.indexOf(elem) === -1 } return false ?

Answer (score 22):

You can use [array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

pseudocode:

```
function arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle, haystack){
  for(var i = 0; i < needle.length; i++){
    if(haystack.indexOf(needle[i]) === -1)
       return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ES6 solution using `includes`:

```
[1].every(elem => [1,2,3].includes(elem));
```

Very similar to Explosion Pills's solution above, just a bit more readable (and arguably a tiny, tiny bit slower).

Answer (score 3):

```
function arr(arr1,arr2)
{
    for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
     {
        if($.inArray(arr1[i],arr2) ==-1)
               //here it returns that arr1 value does not contain the arr2
        else
             // here it returns that arr1 value contains in arr2

     }

}
```