# Check if array contains all elements of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want a function that returns `true` if and only if a given array includes all the elements of a given "target" array. As follows.

```
const target = [ 1, 2, 3,    ];
const array1 = [ 1, 2, 3,    ]; // true
const array2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, ]; // true
const array3 = [ 1, 2,       ]; // false
```

How can I accomplish the above result?

Answer (score 316):

You can combine the [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) methods:

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3],
    array2 = [1,2,3,4],
    array3 = [1,2];

let checker = (arr, target) => target.every(v => arr.includes(v));

console.log(checker(array2, array1));  // true
console.log(checker(array3, array1));  // false
```

Answer (score 51):

The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value. Stands to reason that if you call `every()` on the original array and supply to it a function that checks if every element in the original array is contained in another array, you will get your answer. As such:

```js
const ar1 = ['a', 'b'];
const ar2 = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'z', 'g', 'b'];

if(ar1.every(r => ar2.includes(r))){
  console.log('Found all of', ar1, 'in', ar2);
}else{
  console.log('Did not find all of', ar1, 'in', ar2);
}
```

Answer (score 32):

You can try with [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.

```js
var mainArr = [1,2,3];
function isTrue(arr, arr2){
  return arr.every(i => arr2.includes(i));
}
console.log(isTrue(mainArr, [1,2,3]));
console.log(isTrue(mainArr, [1,2,3,4]));
console.log(isTrue(mainArr, [1,2]));
```

Answer (score 2):

I used Purely Javascript.

```
function checkElementsinArray(fixedArray,inputArray)
{
    var fixedArraylen = fixedArray.length;
    var inputArraylen = inputArray.length;
    if(fixedArraylen<=inputArraylen)
    {
        for(var i=0;i<fixedArraylen;i++)
        {
            if(!(inputArray.indexOf(fixedArray[i])>=0))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(checkElementsinArray([1,2,3], [1,2,3]));
console.log(checkElementsinArray([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]));
console.log(checkElementsinArray([1,2,3], [1,2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES5, then you can simply do this.

```
targetArray =[1,2,3]; 
array1 = [1,2,3]; //return true
array2 = [1,2,3,4]; //return true
array3 = [1,2] //return false

console.log(targetArray.every(function(val) { return array1.indexOf(val) >= 0; })); //true
 console.log(targetArray.every(function(val) { return array2.indexOf(val) >= 0; })); // true
 console.log(targetArray.every(function(val) { return array3.indexOf(val) >= 0; }));// false
```

Answer (score 1):

reduce can be used here as well (but it has O = (N * M) difficulty):

```
const result = target.reduce((acc, el) => {
    return acc && array.includes(el)
}, true);
```

To solve this in more efficient way(O = N + M):

```
const myMap = new Map();

array.forEach(element => myMap.set(element);

const result = target.reduce((acc, el) => {
   return acc && myMap.has(el)
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking if array x contains everything in array y, including requiring multiple occurrences of elements in y to appear multiple times in x:

```js
function arrayContains(x,y) {
  // returns true if array x contains all elements in array y
  return !x.reduce((y,e,t)=>
    (t=y.indexOf(e),t>=0&&y.splice(t,1),y),[...y]).length
}

console.log(arrayContains([1,2,3],   [1,5]))    // false - no 5 present
console.log(arrayContains([1,2,3],   [1,2]))    // true
console.log(arrayContains([1,2,3],   [1,2,2]))  // false - not enough 2s
console.log(arrayContains([2,1,2,3], [2,2,1]))  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

you can compute the difference of the two arrays, if the target becomes empty, that means that all the elements where found ;)

```js
const target = [ 1, 2, 3,    ];
const array1 = [ 1, 2, 3,    ]; // true
const array2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, ]; // true
const array3 = [ 1, 2,       ]; // false

const containsAll = (target, array) => {
  const difference = target.filter(x => !array.includes(x))
  return difference.length === 0
};

console.assert(containsAll(target, array1), "should be true");
console.assert(containsAll(target, array2), "should be true");
console.assert(containsAll(target, array3) === false, "should be false");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const target = [1, 2, 3];
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, ]; // true
const array3 = [1, 2, ];

function check(targetarr, arr) {
  return targetarr.map((e) => {
    return (arr.includes(e)) ? true : false;
  }).every((e) => e === true);
}
console.log(check(target, array1));
console.log(check(target, array2));
console.log(check(target, array3));
```

Answer (score 0):

In term of code this approach may be efficient.
If performance is the priority and in case of large Arrays, you will perhaps consider sorting the arrays first, then use a more efficient way to do this.

Sorry, I just discovered this post and didn't read all the answers, so forgive me if this method is already mentioned.

```js
const target = [ 1, 2, 3,    ];
const array1 = [ 1, 2, 3,    ]; // true
const array2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, ]; // true
const array3 = [ 1, 2,       ]; // false
const array4 = [20,1,6,2,10,3]; // true

function containsAllElmnts(array, target) {
  return target.every(element => array.includes(element));
}

console.log("reference (target) => " + target);

console.log(array1 + " => " + (containsAllElmnts(array1, target)));
console.log(array2 + " => " + (containsAllElmnts(array2, target)));
console.log(array3 + " => " + (containsAllElmnts(array3, target)));
console.log(array4 + " => " + (containsAllElmnts(array4, target)));
```