# Checking if all value of X array is in Y or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two arrays

```
var A = [1,2,3,4,5];
var B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

Now I want to check if all elements of A are exist in B or not like this

```
var A = [1,2,3,4,5];
var B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
// true


var A = [1,2,3,4,5];
var B = [1,2,3,4,5];
// True

var A = [1,2,3,4,5];
var B = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9];
// False
```

I have tried using some like this

```
if(A.some(item => B.includes(item)) {
     return true;
}
```

But it filters the array and returns true if one of the value is true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if array contains all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606337/check-if-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array)

Comment: Check if this following helps you, its similar implementation.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628059/check-if-every-element-in-one-array-is-in-a-second-array

Comment: also you have a typo in your last code snippet, you have forgotten to close the first bracket which comes right after if keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Use [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
var A1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var B1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var A2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var B2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var A3 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var B3 = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9];

console.log(A1.every(item => B1.includes(item)));
console.log(A2.every(item => B2.includes(item)));
console.log(A3.every(item => B3.includes(item)));
```