# Filter an array of objects with an array inside a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, javascript-objects

I am trying to test if the logged in user has the appropriate role to see certain items in the dashboard.

I have an array of objects. These are the items that the user may or may not see:

```js
items: [
    { title: 'Guide', icon: '$guide', component: 'Guide', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor'] },
    { title: 'Courses', icon: '$courses', component: 'Course', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor'] },
    { title: 'Sections', icon: '$sections', component: 'Sections', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin'] },
    { title: 'Units', icon: '$units', component: 'Units', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin'] },
    { title: 'Groups', icon: '$groups', component: 'Groups', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor'] },
    { title: 'Users', icon: '$users', component: 'Users', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor'] },
    { title: 'FAQ', icon: '$faq', component: 'FAG', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor'] },
]
```

and an admin object. This is the user and their permission roles:

```
cid: (...)
email: (...)
emailVerified: (...)
fullPath: (...)
id: undefined
roles: Array(2)
  0: "member"
  1: "pastor"
```

Here is my code:

```
const hasRole = this.items.filter(val => this.admin.roles.includes(val.roles))
return hasRole
```

This code no longer works because the items.roles used to only be a string but I have now made it an array of roles.

I have tried multiple combinations but am struggling to figure this out.

Comment: I suppose your way forward would include writing a "determine if all/some members of subject array are present in an array"-procedure? Show us what you have tried so far. It is also not clear what the `roles` object in the list of items means -- does a user have to play all the roles listed by `roles`, or any of these, in order to be authorized for access to the realm the item describes?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. This is for a menu system. The code should return true if the current user has the same permission (role) as the menu item

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if array contains all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606337/check-if-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array)

Comment: Funny typo in your `items` array?  Should "FAG" be "FAQ"?  Church script... :) :) :)

Comment: Ok, from what I intuitively understand, a procedure named `allowedItems` that returns an array of items an admin (`user`) is authorized to access, can be defined as follows: `const allowedItems = (user, items) => items.filter(item => user.roles.some(role => item.roles.includes(role)));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test if any element in an array satisfies a condition. In this case, the condition would be if the element is found in another array.

```
const hasRole = this.items.filter(val => 
    this.admin.roles.some(role => val.roles.includes(role))
)
return hasRole
```

Change to [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead if all roles in the `this.admin` object should be included to result in a positive result.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is already a solution, anyway I post also mine. If you want to filter the array and get only items with specified role then you can try this:

```js
let items= [
            { title: 'Guide', icon: '$guide', component: 'Guide', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor'] },
            { title: 'Courses', icon: '$courses', component: 'Course', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor'] },
            { title: 'Sections', icon: '$sections', component: 'Sections', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin'] },
            { title: 'Units', icon: '$units', component: 'Units', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin'] },
            { title: 'Groups', icon: '$groups', component: 'Groups', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor'] },
            { title: 'Users', icon: '$users', component: 'Users', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor'] },
            { title: 'FAQ', icon: '$faq', component: 'FAG', claims: '', size: '', roles: ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'pastor'] },
        ]


let admin = {
  roles: {
    0: "member",
    1: "pastor"
  }
}
let filtered = {}
for(role in admin.roles){
  itemsWithSpecificRole = items.filter(val => val.roles.includes(admin.roles[role]))
  Object.assign(filtered, itemsWithSpecificRole)
}

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Hmm, so you are creating an "array", but it's not really an array, just an object with properties like '0', '1', etc?