# Check if an array contains all of the elements of another array

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm making a program that has 2 arrays: Array1: the input form the user, and Array2: an array that the program needs to check. If Array2 has includes all of the elements of Array1, then de program does something.

Oh and I'm making it in html javascript, and not node.js

```
if(Array1 != ""){
        for(i =0; i < Array2.length; i++){
            var currentelem = Array2[i].split("+");
            for(j=0; j < currentelem.length; j++){
                if(Array1.includes(currentelem[j])){
                    alert("asd")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can example data array1 array2?

Comment: There is ambiguity in your question. Would you consider the array `[1,2,3,4]` to contain the array `[1,1]`?

Comment: Prior to actually asking a question you may consider running its title through Google or some other search engine: https://www.google.com/search?q=Check+if+an+array+contains+all+of+the+elements+of+another+array - there are exact matches for this particular one, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606337/check-if-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if array contains all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606337/check-if-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the .every() and .includes()
methods:

```
let array1 = [1,2,3],
    array2 = [1,2,3,4],
    array3 = [1,2];

let checker = (arr, target) => target.every(v => arr.includes(v));

console.log(checker(array2, array1));  // true
console.log(checker(array3, array1));  // false
```

Oh and this was not Original, all the credit goes to user Mohammad Usman you can check him out on https://stackoverflow.com/users/5933656/mohammad-usman

Answer (score 0):

```js
function arrayContains(x,y) {
  // returns true if array x contains all elements in array y
  return !x.reduce((y,e,t)=>
    (t=y.indexOf(e),t>=0&&y.splice(t,1),y),[...y]).length
}

console.log(arrayContains([1,2,3,4,4],[1,2,4,4]))
console.log(arrayContains([1,2,3,4],  [1,2,4,4]))
console.log(arrayContains([1,2,3,4,4],[1,2,4,4,5]))
```