# How to find each value of array in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two different array.

```
arr1 = ["Name", "Company", "HereToSee", "Reason","Signature"]
arr2 = ["Name", "Company", "HereToSee","Signature"]
```

I need to `find each value of arr1` in arr2.
Like : `"Reason" is not in arr2 so return false` 
 what I need :`every value of arr1 should be include in arr2`

Comment: @adiga: I am not looking for diffrence ,but every value of arr1 should be include in arr2

Comment: There are plenty of duplicates for that too. [Determining whether one array contains the contents of another array in JavaScript/CoffeeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514907) and [Check if every element in one array is in a second array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628059)

Comment: Those duplicate questions are *really* outdated. They're literally from 10 years ago ('09). Let's consider this before we mark everything as duplicate. There's ES6 and a lot of things got easier!

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: @Fusseldieb are they really? Check the answers beyond the accepted asnwers. Question is 10 year old, but there are a lot of new answers. There are a lot of linked questions on the right side of those questions, which will be linked to new duplicate questions. There are hundreds of duplicates for this question and OP has done zero research.