# How to check if an array contains all the elements of another another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am having two arrays I need to check if Array(A) contains all the elements of Array(B) but Array(A) can have more elements than Array(B) I have tried with the below code but it is not working as expected.

Below is my code

```
let ArrayA = [{headerName:'No'},{headerName:'zahid'},{headerName:'hussain'}];
let ArrayB = [{headerName:'zahid'},{headerName:'abass'},{headerName:'hussain'}];

checkArrayElements() {
    let value: boolean;
    this.ArrayA.map((element) => {
        value =
            this.ArrayB.find(
                (field: any) => field.headerName == element.headerName
            ) != null;
    });
    return value;
}
```

could anyone please tell me where I am making the mistake?

Comment: So the expected result for the above should be `false`? Since `{headerName:'abass'}` is missing from A

Comment: @NickParsons yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining whether one array contains the contents of another array in JavaScript/CoffeeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514907/determining-whether-one-array-contains-the-contents-of-another-array-in-javascri)

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with your current approach is that you are re setting `value` for every iteration of `.map()` (side note: this should be `.forEach()` and not `.map()` since you are not using the result returned by `.map()` - more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903693/is-performing-a-mapping-operation-without-using-returned-value-an-antipattern/56904505#56904505)). You are currently only checking if the value of the last element in `ArrayA` appears in `ArrayB` as you are not taking into account what the previous values on `value` were. Instead, you can make your outer loop over array B and then use an inner loop to check if the value from array B appears in A.

With that being said, I think I would use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), where you can merge both array elements and remove the duplicates using a Set. The size of the Set should equal the size of ArrayA if there all elements from B appear in ArrayA:

```js
const ArrayA = [{headerName:'No'},{headerName:'zahid'},{headerName:'hussain'}];
const ArrayB = [{headerName:'zahid'},{headerName:'abass'},{headerName:'hussain'}];

const allInBAppearInA = new Set([...ArrayA, ...ArrayB].map(({headerName}) => headerName)).size === ArrayA.length;
console.log(allInBAppearInA);
```

If I was to use a loop approach like explained above, I would use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check that *every* elements from ArrayB can be found in `ArrayA` (you can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check that ArrayA contains an object with a given header name matching one from `ArrayA`):

```js
const ArrayA = [{headerName:'No'},{headerName:'zahid'},{headerName:'hussain'}];
const ArrayB = [{headerName:'zahid'},{headerName:'abass'},{headerName:'hussain'}];

const res = ArrayB.every(({headerName}) => ArrayA.some(obj => obj.headerName === headerName));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using filter (a simplified option)**

```
const value =
      this.ArrayB.filter(f => this.ArrayA.map(m => m.headerName).includes(f.headerName)).length === this.ArrayB.length;
    console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get diffrences between two arrays like this:

```js
let arrayA = [
    { headerName: "No" },
    { headerName: "zahid" },
    { headerName: "hussain" },
  ];
  let arrayB = [
    { headerName: "zahid" },
    { headerName: "abass" },
    { headerName: "hussain" },
  ];

  let firstArray = [];
  let secondArray = [];
  let diffrence = [];
  arrayA.map((objects) => {
    Object.keys(objects).map((key) => firstArray.push(objects[key]));
  });
  arrayB.map((objects) => {
    Object.keys(objects).map((key) => secondArray.push(objects[key]));
  });

  firstArray.map((element) => {
    if (!secondArray.includes(element)) {
      diffrence.push(element);
    }
  });
  secondArray.map((element) => {
    if (!firstArray.includes(element)) {
      diffrence.push(element);
    }
  });

  console.log(diffrence);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can work around this simple implementation:

```js
let ArrayA = [{headerName: 'No'}, {headerName: 'zahid'}, {headerName: 'hussain'}];
let ArrayB = [{headerName: 'zahid'}, {headerName: 'abass'}, {headerName: 'hussain'}];

let checkArrayElements = () => {
  let allPresent = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < ArrayB.length; i++) {

    allPresent = ArrayA.map(a => a.headerName).indexOf(ArrayB[i].headerName) !== -1;
    if (!allPresent)
      break;
  }
  return allPresent;
};
console.log(checkArrayElements());
```